# Basis for the kernel of linear map for linear Diophantine equation in three variables

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modules, linear-diophantine-equations

I am interested in finding general form of the solution of linear Diophantine equation

$$ ax + by +cz = d. $$

We will use notation 
$$
 f : \mathbb{Z^3} \to \mathbb{Z},
$$
$$
f(x,y.z) = ax + by + bz;
$$
for breifity

It is easy to see that if the equation has a solution $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in \mathbb{Z}^3$, then any other solution $(x_0',y_0',z_0')$ can be expressed as 
$$
 (x'_0,y'_0,z'_0) = (x_0,y_0,z_0) + (x'_0 - x_0,y'_0 - y_0,z'_0 - z_0).
$$

It is clear that the last term belongs to the $\ker f$ . So, if the basis $(e_1,e_2)$  of $\ker f$ was known it would be possible to write for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$
  (x'_0,y'_0,z'_0)  = (x_0,y_0,z_0) +  \alpha e_1 + \beta e_2.
$$

Despite that it is easy to get two linearly independent elements $v_1, v_2 \in \ker f$,  as we are working with the ring of scalars which is not a field, it is not true that  $(v_1,v_2)$ always form a basis.

> What are correct expressions  for basis elements $e_1, e_2$?

I can suggest 
$$
v_1 = \left(0, -\frac{c}{\mathrm{gcd}(c,b)}, \frac{b}{\mathrm{gcd}(c,b)} \right),
$$
$$
v_2 = \left( \frac{b}{\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)}, -\frac{a}{\mathrm{gcd}(a.b)}   , 0\right);
$$
for the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something that shows things in general: see the comments at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103152/determinant-of-integer-lattice-basis-of-l-x-1-ldots-x-n-a-1x-1-cdotsa  Note that the Gram determinant I talk about is exactly the square of the volume of the fundamental parallelotope ( parallelogram or parallelepiped or...)

====================================================================

Your pair do not necessarily give a basis for the integral lattice; having finished my part, I will now check the Gram matrix for your basis. If we give new integers $p,q,r,$ I guess also $g, \alpha, \beta,$ with
$$  \gcd(a,b,c) = 1,  $$
$$ pa + q b = g = \gcd(a,b), $$
$$ a = g \alpha, \; \; \;  b = g \beta, $$
then (several) steps lead to basis
$$ v_1 = (-\beta, \alpha, 0), $$
$$ v_2 =( -pc, -qc ,g ).    $$

Let me give the Gram matrix and determinant, need some time

$$
G =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha^2 + \beta^2 & (p \beta - q \alpha) c \\
(p \beta - q \alpha) c & g^2 + (p^2 + q^2) c^2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with
$$ \det G = a^2 + b^2 + c^2  $$

=======================================

Alright, finished yours: if $g = \gcd(a,b)$ and $h = \gcd(b,c)$ then your determinant is
$$ \left( \frac{b^2}{g^2 h^2} \right)  \left( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \right).$$
This is too large, especially in the extreme case when $g=h=1,$ which would happen for the example
$a = 11, b = 13, c = 17.$

================================================

Alright, deriving carefully.
$$ ax+by +cz = 0.   $$
$$  \gcd(a,b,c) = 1,  $$
$$ pa + q b = g = \gcd(a,b), $$
$$ a = g \alpha, \; \; \;  b = g \beta, $$
$$  p \alpha + q \beta = 1. $$
$$  ax+by = -cz  $$
$$ (\alpha x + \beta y) g = - cz. $$
$$ \gcd(g,c) = 1,$$ so that $$ g | z,  $$ let
$$ z = g w.  $$
$$ (\alpha x + \beta y)  = - cw. $$ We have
$$  p \alpha + q \beta = 1, $$ so
$$ (\alpha x + \beta y)  = - c(p \alpha + q \beta)w. $$ 
Move around,
$$  (x+pcw) \alpha = - (y+qcw) \beta. $$
Again,
$$  \gcd(\alpha, \beta) = 1, $$ so
$$ \alpha |  (y+qcw). $$ Let
$$ y+qcw = \alpha t,  $$
$$ x+pcw  = - \beta t   $$
We have constructed integers $t,w$ with
$$ x = \beta t - p c w,    $$
$$ y = \alpha t - q c w,    $$
$$ z = g w.  $$

======================================================================

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Will. Your answer Is very helpful for me. I have red your math-overflow  you don't need to embed screen shots. I will accept your answer latter (In 1 day time or so), if no competitors appear.

Comment: @NikPronko right. Usually I would not bother with screen shots, but my own machine now gives me trouble rendering mathematics in comments, a good portion of the time. No trouble with questions or answers, just comments. In this case, relevant as Prof. Elkies is extremely knowledgeable about integral lattices.  At the same time, he often would prefer to leave a comment or two than bother with a posted answer. I see, Elkies was the doctoral supervisor for Henry Cohn (2000), dissertation New Bounds for Sphere Packing.

Comment: @NikPronko see http://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201702/rnoti-p102.pdf  written by Henry. It takes a while to render, some high quality photographs