# Number Theory - Solving an Equation using Modular Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Solve
>   $$49x+59y+75z=0 $$
>   for $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$

Please use modular arithmetic. By trial and error I got that the solution is $x=-7, y=2, z=3$. I have solved a similar equation with $2$ variables using modular arithmetic but am unsure how to proceed on one with $3$ variables.

I would like to find the solution stated above, a non trivial solution.

Comment: Let $c1,c2\in\mathbb Z$ be some constants, then $x=c_1,y=64c_1+75c_2,z=-51c_1-59c_2$. Notice that there are infinitely many solutions. The solution you've found is for $c1=-7$ and $c_2=6$.

Comment: @ThePirateBay I would like to use modular arithmetic and would like to find the smallest solution. I am unsure where the numbers are coming from above. I am a beginner to working in modulo and would appreciate a thorough explanation!

Comment: @KassidySeldon What do you mean by the *smallest* solution?

Comment: @MathLover I am aware that there are infinitely many solutions however I would like the smallest/simplest one!

Comment: @KassidySeldon Well the simplest solution is $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @MathLover sorry I meant non-trivial. Short and sweet I want to obtain the answer in my original post

Comment: Kassidy general method at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488074/basis-for-the-kernel-of-linear-map-for-linear-diophantine-equation-in-three-vari/2488307#2488307   Your three coefficients are coprime so things come out simpler.

Comment: where are they getting that a= p(alpha) and b=q(beta)? @WillJagy

Comment: Kassidy, there was a typo. the gcd is $g,$ each of $a,b$ is divisible by $g,$ and then the remaining factors are coprime, those being $\alpha = a/g$ and $\beta = b / g.$ Tat is, $\gcd(\alpha, \beta) = 1$

Comment: Then the Extended Euclidean Algorithm finds a pair $p,q$ such that $pa+qb = g$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$49\mid 59y+75z \Longrightarrow 49\mid 10y -23z \Longrightarrow 49\mid 50y -115z \Longrightarrow 49\mid y -17z $$
So we have $y-17z = 49t$ for some $t\in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $$y = 17z+49t$$ and $$x= -22z-59t$$
where we can choose $z$ arbitrary.

Comment: Note that this answer has the form $(x,y,z)=z(-22,17,1)+t(-59, 49,0)$ and $z=3, t=-1$ gives the solution $(-7, 2, 3)$

Comment: could you explain how you solved for x here

Comment: I have pluged in equation for $y$ in to starting equation.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can reduce this a bit, by reducing the coefficients, but giving yourself more work at the end, is to put $a=x+y+z$ so that $$49a+10y+26z=0$$

Now put $b=4a+y+2z$ so that $$9a+10b+6z=0$$

Here you already have $b=3c$ a multiple of $3$ and $a=2d$ is necessarily a multiple of $2$.

$$18d+30c+6z=0$$ or $$3d+5c+z=0$$

Choose $c$ and $d$ as you wish, and $z$ is now determined $z=-3d-5c$.

We have $b=3c$, $a=2d$.

Now $y=b-4a-2z =3c-8d+6d+10c=13c-2d$

And $x=a-y-z=2d-13c+2d+3d+5c=7d-8c$

Putting this together, for any integers $c,d$ there is a solution $$x=7d-8c$$$$ y= 13c-2d$$$$ z=-3d-5c$$

Your solution corresponds to $c=0, d=-1$

---

For "small" solutions it depends what you mean by small. Any of $x, y, z$ can be made equal to zero, but that gives large numbers elsewhere (excluding the all zero solution).

---

What you have here is a single linear homogeneous equation in three variables. If $X$ and $Y$ are triples which solve the equation then so does $aX+bY$. Here the solution is given in the form $$(x,y,z)=c(-8,13,-5)+d(7,-2,-3)$$
This has the features we expect - it is linear, and the solution space has dimension $2$ as we would expect having one linear constraint on a three variable linear problem.
I am not sure what advantage you see in using modular arithmetic rather than linear algebra (either ad hoc or general techniques). When you reduce modulo some integer, you still have a linear system to solve, and then you have to lift the solution to the original context.
I have used such observations as $b$ is a multiple of $3$ - which is an implicit use of modulo $3$ for example. Examining the form of the solution, what modulus do you think might help to find that?

Comment: I understand this solution but is this possible to do using modular arithmetic?

Comment: I want to obtain the solution in my initial post but using modulo

Comment: @KassidySeldon I've added some comments at the end. I don't think modular arithmetic is really the answer here.

Comment: We are currently studying a chapter on modular arithmetic so that is why I ask! Thank you for your help.